Conditions on coefficients of double convergent series for it to be holomorphic and complex harmonic
I am working on an exercise from a graduate first year complex analysis class. The problem states:
let $f: D \to \mathbb{C}$ given by $ f = u + iv$. Assume that $f$ admits an absolutely convergent double power series expansion $$ f(z, \overline{z})= \sum_{n,m = 0}^\infty a_{n \overline{m}} z^n \overline{z}^m $$ and that usual differentiation and integration rules for power series in one variable apply.
 i) Under what conditions on the coefficients $a_{n \overline{m}} $ is the function holomorpic in $D$
 ii) Under what conditions on the coefficients $a_{n \overline{m}} $ is the function complex harmonic in $D$.
What I have tried so far:
 i) f is holomorphic if $\frac{\partial}{\partial \overline{z}} f= 0$, i.e.
$$0 = \frac{\partial}{\partial \overline{z}} \sum_{n,m = 0}^\infty a_{n \overline{m}} z^n \overline{z}^m = \sum_{n,m = 0}^\infty \frac{\partial}{\partial \overline{z}} a_{n \overline{m}} z^n \overline{z}^m  = \sum_{n,m = 0}^\infty a_{n \overline{m}} z^n (m\overline{z}^{m-1})$$ Where we could pass derivative under the sum since the series is absolutely convergent. Since this has to hold for every $z$ and $\overline{z}$ we must have $a_{n \overline{m}} = 0$ for every $n,m \in \mathbb{N}$.
 ii) f is complex harmonic if $Re(f)$ and $Im(f)$ are harmonic. We know that
$$ Re(f) = \frac{f+\overline{f}}{2}, \quad Im(f) = \frac{f - \overline{f}}{2i}, \quad \frac{1}{4} \Delta u = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial z \partial \overline{z}} u
 $$
Then
\begin{align}
0 = \frac{1}{4} \Delta Re(f) & = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial z \partial \overline{z}} \frac{1}{2}\left( \sum_{n,m = 0}^\infty a_{n \overline{m}} z^n \overline{z}^m  + \sum_{n,m = 0}^\infty \overline{a_{n \overline{m}}} \overline{z}^n z^m \right) \\\\ 
&= \frac{1}{2} \sum_{n,m = 0}^\infty a_{n \overline{m}} mn z^{n-1} \overline{z}^{m-1} + \overline{a_{n \overline{m}}} mn \overline{z}^{n-1}z^{m-1}
\end{align}
So $$a_{n \overline{m}} mn z^{n-1} \overline{z}^{m-1} = - \overline{a_{n \overline{m}}} mn \overline{z}^{n-1}z^{m-1} $$
Similarly from the laplacian of the imaginary part we get $$ a_{n \overline{m}} mn z^{n-1} \overline{z}^{m-1} =  \overline{a_{n \overline{m}}} mn \overline{z}^{n-1}z^{m-1} $$
Then we must have $$ a_{n \overline{m}} = 0$$
I do not think this is correct but have no better ideas. I am looking for feedback and suggestions on how to do this problem.

What is the purpose of putting a bar over the index $m$ in $a_{n \overline{m}}$?

I am not sure, but this is how the problem was phrased in the exercise. My guess is that it emphasizes that m index is for $ \overline{z} $

(I'll use $n, m$ for the indices instead of $n, \overline m$.)
For the first part, note that the derivative of $z^n {\overline z}^m$ with to $\overline z$ is zero if $m=0$. So we have
$$
 \frac{\partial}{\partial \overline{z}} f = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{m=1}^\infty m a_{nm} z^n {\overline z}^{m-1}
$$
and that is identically zero if (and only if) $a_{nm} = 0$ for $m \ge 1$, that is if
$$
 f(z, \overline z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{n0} z^n \, .
$$
In other words, $f$ is holomorphic in $D$ exactly if $ f(z, \overline z) = g(z)$ with a holomorphic function $g$.
For the second part there is no need to compute $\Delta u$ and $\Delta v$ separately. $f$ is harmonic in $D$ if $\Delta f$ is zero. Similar as in the first part we get
$$
 \frac 14 \Delta f = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial z \partial \overline{z}} f
= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{m=1}^\infty nm a_{nm} z^{n-1} {\overline z}^{m-1}
$$
and that is identically zero if $a_{nm} = 0$ whenever $n\ge 1$ and $m \ge 1$, that is if
$$
 f(z, \overline z) = a_{00} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n0} z^n + \sum_{m=0}^\infty a_{0m} {\overline z}^m \,.
$$
In other words, $f$ is harmonic in $D$ exactly if $ f(z, \overline z) = g(z) + h(\overline z)$ with holomorphic functions $g$ and $h$.

Thank you very much. It makes a lot of sense.
